# VS2015 RC to RTM Cordova project nuked

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015

I just updated my install of VS2015 from RC to RTM.

I was working on a mobile app with cordova tools. After the upgrade, every time I try to build the app, this appears:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Appsow, Configuration: Debug Android ------
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I already switched the build verbosity to Diagnostic in option: still no other words than these.

I figured out that the NPM folder

```
C:\Users\Valerio\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
```

is empty.

Installed cordova, tried to compile, still the same not-very-diagnostic error.

Looking for some other people with my same destiny, I realized that I also need to add via npm the VS-MDA tool.
I found in

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\ApacheCordovaTools
```

the folder VS-MDA-TARGETS but it's no use.

FWIW I already tried to repair the VS installation, and then again via remove/reinstall.

Please help! I don't want to format and reinstall everything! :(

thanks in advance
Valerio

Comment: Same problem here :-(  Currently running a VS installer "repair".

Comment: @SPDoctor no luck for me with repair. Even tried to repair the sole apache cordova tools. Still here to pray

Comment: @SPDoctor did the repair succeded?

Comment: Nope :-(. I am now trying to uninstall VS2015RTM and reinstall VS2015RC. Don't want to re-pave as I plan to do so next week for Windows 10 anyway.

Comment: I tryied to uninstall rtm and reinstall RC . no luck.

Comment: OK, thanks. Might try to struggle on with VS2013 with CTP3.1 but I think reality is that the Cordova tools relies on a bunch of installers for third party components, any of which could have got into a SNAFU state. Beginning to think re-pave machine is only option.

Comment: Do you have a correct package.json or bower.json in your project root to tell it your dependencies? And does your taco.json indicate cordova-cli 4.3.1?

Comment: Failing that I would create a new empty project and see if it builds. Then perhaps move your code across.

Comment: Already tried creating a new project - same problem.

Comment: Same problem here. And believe me, I tried everything. Now, just for fun, I vm'd a fresh install of W8.1 and I'm installing the vs2015 RTM. Just to know if my machine is stale.

Comment: Re-installed Windows 8.1 and installed Visual Studio 2015 and all working okay, which confirms that the RC must have left something behind, presumably node.js.

Answer (score 0):

Disable iOS remote processing.

I had iOS remote processing configured under 2015 RC, and I was getting the same build failure, with no console output, even after following the steps outlined by @Jon Z. I changed "Enable remote iOS processing" to false and was able to build Cordova projects again.

I haven't tried setting up the new iOS remote agent yet to see if the configuration process fixes whatever issue the RC -> RTM upgrade created.

Comment: On my scenario, I resolved paving the workstation. But node.js seems to be the problem. 
IMHO anyway, VS2015 has a lame implementation of these tools. It's pretty much better to go via command line, the use vs for the coding, and rely a very little (to none) to implementations. 
In a real scenario, cmd tools are quicker, and more up-to-date.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm this solution works.

1. Close all VS instances
2. cd “%appdata%..\Local\Microsoft\Phone Tools”
3. rename CoreCon folder
4. Launch VS again.