# Cannot Run Cordova App in Visual Studio 2015 Update 1

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

I have installed VS2015 Update 1 Without internet And Then given Path going in `Tools > Options > Tools For Apache Cordova > Environment Variables` override and give path for `ADT`, `ANT`, `GIT` And `Java` And then Go to `VS2015 Update 1` setup and run repair. I created a basic html and then try to build. It builded succesfully but cannot find any emulators to run when i try to run by click start button from tool bar `Selected debug > Selected Android` And click on start but it gives error

> Unable to start debugging

I tried installing simulator I am running `windows 10 64bit` then also it shows me error that you should be running `windows 8 pro 64 bit` or later

Comment: In the toolbar, next to the button you mention that says "Start", do you see a drop-down menu? If you do, there should be options you can pick from in there, such as Device, Ripple, an emulators. Do any of those options work for you?

Comment: There is drop down which contains only start again and nothing else

Comment: install ripple emulator https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ripple-emulator-beta/geelfhphabnejjhdalkjhgipohgpdnoc?hl=en

Comment: @ALex I already accepted the answer down there and that was the solution and thanks btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a known issue with the tools where an internal component can be corrupted when upgrading your environment. (I'm curious, did you recently upgrade your version of Visual Studio?)

You can see some troubleshooting steps in this post: [Unable to start debugging in Visual Studio RTM for cordova app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31530014/unable-to-start-debugging-in-visual-studio-rtm-for-cordova-app)

The important part is to do the following:

> 1. Close all VS instances
> 2. [Open a command line and] `cd %appdata%\"..\Local\Microsoft\Phone Tools"`
> 3. rename CoreCon folder to something else: [`rename CoreCon CoreConBackup`]
> 4. Launch VS again.

If that rename works, you can remove the CoreConBacupk folder.

Comment: Its working thanks. I was messing with this for 5 days and no luck but this is the solution thanks a lot